# Getting tkinter widget values outside main application class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter, pygame, logic

I have a pygame project which has a main menu - in said menu I have it so that upon clicking the <kbd>Options</kbd> button it triggers a Tkinter UI to open. The UI has a `OptionMenu` widget affecting game speed. How do I retrieve the value of the `OptionMenu` outside the class I used to create the Tkinter window

Here is a simplified issue:

```
class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import Tk  # etc...
        # CODE FOR THE PROGRAM WINDOW
        defaultSpeed = StringVar(root)
        speedMenu = OptionMenu(root, defaultSpeed, 'Slow', 'Normal, 'Fast')
        speedMenu.pack()
```

I know I need `defaultSpeed.get()` to get the value.

The Pygame menu has this:

```
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
clicked = click[0] == 1
if "Play" clicked:
   startGame(ticks)
if "Options" clicked:
   options = GUI()
```

At this point ^^^ How do I somehow obtain the speed (`defaultSpeed.get()`) and have it as global variable so that I can use it in the `startGame` function to affect the number of ticks on clock?

Thinking about it, I'm essentially asking for how to have a global variable defined when initialising a Tkinter class?

I've tried creating a function in GUI() called `getSpeed` and calling `options.getSpeed()` but for some reason I still have a logic error that means it's never actually printed/displayed/returned.

I am aware you shouldn't return values when in `__init__` - should I just move all my Tkinter app. to a function inside `GUI()` and leave the `__init_` out? surely I could just refrain from initalising it? Would this be better off programmed procedurally over OOP (allowing me to simply call `GUI()` in the main menu)?

Any help solving is appreciated.

**RECAP OF PROBLEM:**

1. Main Menu has 2 options (1 runs game in Pygame, 1 runs Options window in Tkinter)
2. I need to get the option from the options menu and have it apply to a variable in the game.

**EDIT: I was asked to provide a minimal code**
I'm currently really busy but here is minimal pseudocode - all you need to do is create the dimensions for the game window and for the menu (they are both 940,500)

```
import pygame
import time
import math
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.tick.Clock()
ticks = 0

#Here is all the game code

#This function is the main game and includes the game loop
def StartGame(ticks):
    running = True
    myGame1 = teams()
    myGame1.startTeam()
    #Here is some functions providing the rules of the sport
    def updateBall(ticks):
        theBall.x += float(theBall.speed) * ticks / 1000
    while running:
        myGame1.displayPlayers()
        updateBall(ticks)
        #Calling alot of functions and the game running is here
        ticks = clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.flip
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
            quit

def game_intro(menu_image):
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        clicked = click[0] == 1

        if 62+288 > mouse[0] > 62 and 150+28 > mouse[1] > 150:
            if clicked:
                startGame(ticks)
                pass

        elif 62+288 > mouse[0] > 62 and 230+30 > mouse[1] > 230:
            if clicked:
                options = GUI()

class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root = self.root = tkinter.Tk
        root.geometry('500x400')
        root.configure(background = '#ffffff')
        speedLabel = tkinter.Message(root, text = 'Game speed: ')

        defaultSpeed = StringVar(root)
        speedMenu = OptionMenu(root,defaultSpeed, 'Slow', 'Normal', 'Fast')

        speedLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        speedMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

game_intro(menu_image)
```

Comment: Your code snippets are a little _too_ sparse. Please [edit] your question and put enough in it to create a minimal, runnable example, that we can use for testing solutions for you. It also sounds like you're using Python 2.x. Regardless, please add a tag indicating the proper version.

Comment: With all due respect, I believe what I've included is enough for someone to mock up a small similar program - I am really busy at the moment but have mocked up a small program which is near identical to the logic of my larger project. Please let me know if you think you need more - in essence the problem needs someone to create a small options screen in Tkinter and have it called in a simple Pygame main menu window. You dont even need the main game however i've included it in the edited pseudocode.

Comment: Why should everyone who wants to help you have to mock something up? A little more work is expected from the person asking the question...

Comment: All that needs to be done is creating two windows - I have included the main parts needed for an example. Nobody is obligated to do anything but I have a lot going on in the next 20 minutes - being a student - and can't afford to sit and argue this. I honestly appreciate your comments and I dont expect the help to create a mock up, somebody may know the answer from seeing the code snippets. Thanks, Rowan

Comment: Do you know about `global`?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Yes but i'm not sure how to use it properly in this scenario? any ideas?

Comment: Added an answer explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you create `defaultSpeed`:

```
global defaultSpeed
```

Then before you access it:

```
global defaultSpeed
```

It basically means that you can access the variable from anywhere after using `global`.